# ARKit 4.0 – Is it possible to convert ARWorldMap data to JSON file?

Tags: json, swift, xml, augmented-reality, arkit

I'd like to know whether it is possible to convert a `worldMap` binary data (that stores a space-mapping state and set of ARAnchors) to `json` or `xml` file?

```
func writeWorldMap(_ worldMap: ARWorldMap, to url: URL) throws {

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, 
                                         requiringSecureCoding: true)
    try data.write(to: url)
}
```

If this possible, what tools can I use for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am afraid that the only way to do this is by wrapping the `ARWorldMap` object into a `Codable` object like that:

```
struct ARData {
    var worldMap: ARWorldMap?
}

extension ARData: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case worldMap
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let worldMapData = try container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .worldMap)
        worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: worldMapData)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        if let worldMap = worldMap {
            let colorData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            try container.encode(colorData, forKey: .worldMap)
        }
    }
}
```

To encode an instance of that object to JSON use the `encode(:)` function of the `JSONEncoder`:

```
let arData = ARData(worldMap: worldMap)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(arData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

By default, `JSONEncoder` will convert the `ARWorldMap` data to a Base64 string that can be read using `JSONDecoder`:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(ARData.self, from: jsonData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```